# Log "Info Context Menu" to file

Tags: python

Best case scenario: All commands that appear in the "Info Context Menu" are logged to a file.

I tried [`bpy.ops.info.select_all()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html) thinking I could at least copy all the lines and write them to a file.

But I can't figure out which "context" I need to be in to use this function.

```py
>>> bpy.ops.info.select_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ian/Downloads/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 115, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.info.select_all.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Is there a way to set up a logger for for the commands that appear in the window at the bottom?

[image: Console Menu & Info Context Menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`bpy.ops.info.select_all()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html#bpy.ops.info.select_all) requires that the area is of type `INFO`. This can be achieved by supplying an overridden context.

In versions prior to Blender 3.2.x this can be implemented by copying the current context and modifying the `area` in the copy. This context is then supplied as the first argument when calling the operator. This is documented in [Blender's Python API manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.1/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context).

In version Blender 3.2.x the override is created through [`bpy.context.temp_override()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override). This is documented in [Blender's Python API manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context). The other approach has been deprecated.

The example below assumes that there is an existing area with type `INFO`.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "INFO":
        if bpy.app.version < (3, 2, 0):
            override = bpy.context.copy()
            override["area"] = area
            bpy.ops.info.select_all(override)
            bpy.ops.info.report_copy(override) 
        else:
            with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
                bpy.ops.info.select_all()
                bpy.ops.info.report_copy()
        break
```

The clipboard content copied with [`bpy.ops.info.report_copy()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.info.html#bpy.ops.info.report_copy) can be accessed through [`bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.clipboard).

```
with open("F:\\some\\example\\path\\clipboard.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard)
```